# Implication and conclusion in propositional calculus

Tags: propositional-calculus

Let A and B be any propositions expressible in the propositional calculus notation.

Show that A $\vdash$ B is provable by the rules of propositional calculus if and only if it is provable that $\vdash$ (A $\rightarrow$ B).

In proving that if $\vdash$ (A $\rightarrow$ B) is provable, then A $\vdash$ B is provable, I have the following:

1 (1) A $\rightarrow$ B $\:\:\:\:$ A

2 (2) A $\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$A

1,2 (3) B $\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$MP 1, 2

$\therefore$ A $\vdash$ B is provable.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it is correct.  Also, yes you are missing something - the "only if" part of your statement.

Comment: @David - I have already proven the other half of the statement, I only needed help on this part.

Comment: That's ok then.